# SCSS: How to combine @for with @each?

Tags: html, sass

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">first</div>
  <div class="col">second</div>
  <div class="col">third</div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$statistics: ("first", "second", "third");

:root {
  --first: red;
  --second: blue;
  --third: green;
}

.row {
  @for $i from 1 through length($statistics) {
    @each $variable in $statistics {
      .col:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        color: var(--#{$variable});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**i want to compile it like**

```
.row {
  .col:nth-child(1) {
    color: var(--first);
  }
  .col:nth-child(2) {
    color: var(--second);
  }
  .col:nth-child(3) {
    color: var(--third);
  }
}
```

Where am I wrong? Each **.col** has all 3 colors. I want each statistic to have only one color in order in $statistics. The first **.col** had the first, the second **.col** the second etc ...

**EDIT**
what if the variables are defined like this?

```
$statistics: (
  "header": ("first", "second", "third")
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have a first loop with `@for` looping through all the values of `$statistics` and then `@each` doing the same which results in repeated values. This should be done with a single loop. I can think of two ways of achieving what you want:

```
.row {
  @for $i from 1 through length($statistics) {
    $variable: nth($statistics, $i);

    .col:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        color: var(--#{$variable});
      }
  }
}
```

or

```
.row {
 @each $variable in $statistics {
     $i: index($statistics, $variable);
      .col:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        color: var(--#{$variable});
      }
  }
}
```

In the case of the variable defined as:

```
$statistics: (
  "header": ("first", "second", "third")
);
```

You can use `map-get` to obtain the variables. Something like:

```
$header: map-get($statistics, "header");

@each $variable in $header {
    $i: index($header, $variable);

    .col:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      color: var(--#{$variable});
    }
}
```

This is the same as before but looping with `$header` instead of `$statistics`

Comment: Thanks, works. I still have a question, what if the variables are defined differently? Look at my edit. Is it possible to use map.get here, or how should I edit it?

Comment: @TheCzechTayen I updated my answer for the case you mentioned. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, u helped me a lot.

Comment: @TheCzechTayen glad to help.